# Chrome garbage collector going crazy

Tags: google-chrome, extjs, garbage-collection

Using Version 48.0.2564.109 m.

We have a javascript web app (built with ExtJS). In Chrome, when we leave our app sitting there for a while, the GC starts going nuts.  In Task Manager, you can see the CPU constantly spinning around 25%.

I took timeline snapshots and CPU profiles, and you can see the GC, about 10 times a seconds, try to collect memory, but collects 0B.

Our app is a large enterprise application and does use quite a bit of memory and updates the screen periodically.

But, there is absolutely no javascript code running during this time.  So I can't see that it is something our app is actively doing

Does anyone know what could be triggering this?

It is killing performance of our app.

Also, it only happens when our tab is active.  If you switch to a different tab, the CPU dies down and the GC stops.

Is there other data I need to collect to help determine this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is your app current JS heap size? You can check it by collecting timeline and enabling memory check box.

It looks like your app is close to the V8 memory limit, so V8 is trying to free some memory. If it is expected for the app to use that much memory, you can increase the limit on your host with something like: --js-flags="--max-old-space-size=2048"

Otherwise it might be just a memory leak in your code. Use heap profiler to hunt it down.

Comment: Thanks, we are definitely using a lot of memory at that point, so I'm guessing you are correct.  What you say makes a lot of sense.  I will investigate more and report back.  Thanks!